# Error: failed to send request to https://test.salesforce.com**** when using Talend

Tags: error, talend

I am trying to upload attachments (more than 500 attachments) from talend to Salesforce, It works for the first few 10, 20 attachments and then it crashes, i run the job multiple times and always get the same result:

```
failed to release the resource in tSalesforceOutput_1 :com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://lbp-ic--dev.cs88.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0/00D9E000000CxaC
```

Here is a my talend job:

[image]

Do you have an idea to workaround this problem ?

Comment: Hi, is it possible for you to use bulk salesforce plugins and use bulk api and see if that works ?

Comment: Yes, i will try it right away and keep you updated.

Comment: The bulk api , it works for to insert or retrieve data from Salesforce ?

Comment: Yes it should work same as like what we do in the dataloader

Comment: Any Luck ? in getting this ?

Comment: Actually,i am struggling in getting this in place, i am facing some non-expected errors. I will will be back shortly with the result.